# Neo4j: How to calculate year difference between particular date and today's date in neo4j 3.x version?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have nodes with person label where i am storing their date of births too. For e.g.:

```
Person
{
  name: Tim
  D.O.B: 01/23/1990
}
```

Now I need to calculate his age as of current date and time ( i.e. either 27 years or  27 years, 10 months, 18 days ). So, could anyone let me know how could I perform it?

P.S.: I tried the following but seems to be missing something here :

```
WITH apoc.date.parse('01/23/1990', 'y', 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS startDate,
     apoc.date.format(timestamp(),'y','MM/dd/yyyy') as endDate,
     apoc.date.parse(endDate,'y','MM/dd/yyyy') as ed

 RETURN ed - 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The units supported by the APOC date format/parse/add/convert functions are: `ms,s,m,h,d and their long forms`. To work with months, you need to be working with a specific calendar system, and there is no common month unit of time to do conversions or additions, as different months are comprised of different days (then there's the leap days in February).

For years, you're going to have to go with day units and use division by 365.

Here's a query that will get you age in years and days.

```
WITH apoc.date.parse('01/23/1990', 'd', 'MM/DD/yyyy') as birth, apoc.date.convert(timestamp(), 'ms', 'd') as now
WITH now - birth as daysAlive
RETURN daysAlive / 365 as yearsAlive, daysAlive % 365 as daysExtra
```

If you want to get into months, it may be better to work with the month/year fields from the MM/DD/yyyy representation and pull some mathematics on those. I'll see about what we can for supporting that in APOC.

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon, really helpful and insightful comment as well as solution. And really love to see the support in apoc for month.year fields too !

Answer (score 0):

Some like

```
WITH apoc.date.parse('01/23/1990', 'y', 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS startDate
RETURN apoc.date.convert(timestamp() - startDate,"ms","d");
```

perhaps ?

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: thanks for the reply..this one also seems to be quite useful :)